# Can't listen on anything but localhost (ASP.NET MVC Framework IIS Express)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I'm unable to get a ASP.NET MVC project to listen on anything except localhost.

If I change

```
      <IISUrl>http://localhost:2319/</IISUrl>
```

to

```
      <IISUrl>http://eadev:2319/</IISUrl>
```

my project won't even load.

I get the following error:

> Creation of the virtual directory http://eadev:2319 failed with the error: Cannot create the Web site 'http://eadev:2319'. You must specify "localhost" for the server name.

I've seen just tons of issues on this, and someone in my own company has this working, but I cannot get it to work.  I actually set him up.  And I still can't do this.

I've tried

```
netsh http add url=http://eadev:2319 users=everyone
```

That just gives me access denied errors when I run it from the console, but it's still trying to load `localhost:2319`

I deleted the `.vs` directory.  I added entries to the `.vs/app/config/applicationhosts.config`

I've added `eadev` to the hosts file.

Also, one thing that used to work is that I downloaded nginx for Windows and setup a reverse proxy, but now it just says bad gateway. I even setup an ssh tunnel (wouldn't work).  I'm assuming now it's being picky about headers. I can access `http://localhost:2319`, but not nginx `proxy_pass http://localhost:2319` is now giving bad gateway, but it used to work. If I point the `proxy_pass` to `http://example.org` it works.

I found out that nginx is resolving to `127.0.0.1` and IIS Express just won't respond.

There are just so many answers to this and other people seem to have got it working, but I cannot.

Comment: You cannot because you didn't keep IIS Express config file in sync with your project file. https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background The site binding is critical here, and deleting `.vs` directory won't give you the right settings (as VS by default generates localhost only bindings). Keep in mind there are tons of settings for such a project, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: @LexLi I've tried editing the applicationhost.config several times.  I've added new bindings.  Is that what you mean? Rider overwrites the applicationhost.config file every time with the same bad settings.  Visual Studio ignores any new bindings I put in.  Visual studio also shows the url as http://localhost:2319 greyed out and disabled in the property box so I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

I just did some testing.

1. You don't need anything else (like nginx) but IIS Express.
2. You cannot change `IISUrl` now in .csproj. VS seems to have some extra validation in place.
3. You have to register in HTTP API with `netsh http add urlacl url=http://eadev:2319/ user=everyone` if you don't run VS as administrator.
4. You need an extra site binding `*:2319:eadev` in `applicationHost.config` in .vs folder, and IIS Express will try to bind to that.
5. Configure DNS (or hosts file) to map `eadev` to 127.0.0.1.

With all above, when you debug in VS, IIS Express monitors both the localhost site binding, as well as the one you added. Since VS launches the browser to the localhost URL, you might open your own browser tab to navigate to `http://eadev:2319/`.

Comment: `netsh http add urlacl url=http://eadev:2319/ user=everyone` `URL reservation successfully added` `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:2319:eadev" />` `127.0.0.1 eadev` `curl eadev:2319` `Connection refused` `curl localhost:2319` `400 hostname invalid`.  I removed the binding after that and was getting timeouts on localhost until I `netsh http del urlacl url=http://eadev:2319`

Comment: @Bluebaron You are using MinGW's curl which you didn't mention until posting on Server Fault. What happens if you use a browser to navigate to http://eadev:2319/ with everything I mentioned? Also you should use a clean machine (I doubt your previous changes if not reverted properly can come in the way).